# jQuery loop through TD and check values with same attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to loop through all my currently displayed tables using the **td** attribute.

```
var name = "";
var theCell = "";
var width1 = "";
var width2 = "";
var intX = 0;

$("td").each(function (inx) {
     name = $(this).data("colname");

     theCell = $('[data-colname="' + name + '"]')[0];
     console.log(theCell);

     if (typeof theCell != 'undefined') {
          width1 = theCell.scrollWidth;   
          width2 = theCell.clientWidth;

          //console.log(width1);

          if (width1 > width2) {
               //console.log(theCell);
               $(theCell).ellipsis({ lines: 1 });
               $(theCell).css({ 'background-color': '#000' });
          }
     }
});
```

The output of **console.log(theCell)**:

```
<td data-colname="number_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">1</td>
<td data-colname="line_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">1</td>
<td data-colname="network_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">Welcome 1</td>
...more here...
<td data-colname="number_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">45</td>
<td data-colname="line_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">2</td>
<td data-colname="network_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">Welcome 2</td>
...more here...
<td data-colname="number_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">23</td>
<td data-colname="line_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">775</td>
<td data-colname="network_0" class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 80px;">Welcome 3</td>
...more here...etc etc...
```

And on the page it looks like this:

[image]

However, It seems to just loop through the first **td** and that's all. I figured its due to the **[0]** but I'm not sure what needs to be done in order for it to loop through *each* **td**?

It is loop through each TD since I have it all wrapped inside the **jquery each** function but it just keeps looping at the first **td** row. Each row is named the same thing (aka **data-colname="number_0"**, **data-colname="line_0"**, etc...) so I cant look for that to distinguish from one row to another..

Comment: Each loop is getting the same `$('[data-colname="' + name + '"]')`.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to create a selector to find the same element as in previous line. Also that selector will always return first td in page with that attribute

Comment: There are a ton of problems with the code but what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to modify the display of each cell that you're looping through?  It looks like you're trying to re-select any cells that match that data attribute but are then only selecting the first element that returns (as a DOM node, not jQuery object)... is that what you want?  If you're trying to modify the cell you're "on" then you could use `$(this)`...  You probably don't want all those variables outside the scope of the `each` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want to do this:

```
$('td').each(function (index, elem) {
    if (elem.scrollWidth > elem.clientWidth) {
        // console.log(elem);
        $(elem).ellipsis({ lines: 1 }).css({ 'background-color': '#000' });
    }
});
```

Including the second parameter in the [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) handler gives you direct access to the element being looped over.

This line in your code:

```
theCell = $('[data-colname="' + name + '"]')[0];
```

will only ever pull back the first `td` because of the `[data-colname="' + name + '"]` selector as each row in your table appears to share the same `data-colname` attribute.

Comment: That was it Pete! Thanks!